# Different values for Pageviews for two Google Analytics properties in Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my website I noticed a sudden downfall on some metrics. I track it with Google Analytics and Google Tag Manger and since I've made some changes in several tags, I decided to temporarly a secondary Google Analytics property, for debuggin purposes.

Well, the two has the same values, as expected) **but** different pageviews.

This is what my debug GA says:
[image: my debug GA]

And this my original one:
[image: my original GA]

Difference in Sessions are too small to be significant.

But not the same with Pageviews, in my opinion. Weird enough, further analysis shows that the difference is only in Pageviews and **not** in "Unique Pageviews" (they match perfectly).

This is really weird to me as the fact that unique pageviews match means the pageview event was fired, ence was not a problem with the GTM Tag.

Original/Debug are almost the same, after the forementioned exception rule (for logged users) and the allowLinker=False parameter (absent in Debug). Can those cause these discrepancies?

Comment: allowLinker is false by default, so that´s not it.

Answer (score 0):

From the data provided.

The fact that you have two more sessions and a lot less pageviews, leads me to think that you are not tracking all your pages.

If you do some filtering and have multiple GA tags, ensure that you use the exact same trigger you use for exclusion as a fire on on the second dag. You can easily check this visually by looking for the indented blue labels, that these are matched by the same label as inclusion on other tags.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try adding the same exceptions I have in the original GA tag, one per daty, and check when pageviews starts to diverse. Still weird that "unique pageviews" already match, actually. tnx for answer, I'll keep informed